# Ошибка composer install: An error occurred while removing the VCS metadata: Could not delete

Tags: git, composer, permissions, vagrant

Всем привет!
Возможно уже обсуждалось. Но не знаю как правильно сформулировать. В общем на windows 10 установлено Oracle VM и Vagrant. Запускаю виртуалку с образом Ubuntu 20.04. Внутри установил composer version 2.7.1. Так же установлен git version 2.25.1. Запуск composer install начинает ставить приложение и в какой-то момент выдает ошибку типа

```
An error occurred while removing the VCS metadata: Could not delete /vagrant/study/.git/objects/pack/pack-af98e90e8fd5211a9297d48e9e52dfff9f539b5a.idx:
```

Права на этот файлы в этой папке `-r-xr-xr-x`, а в других папках `-rwxrwxrwx`.
Уточнение: удалить файл из папки `.git` командой `rm` в Ubuntu не удается.
Предполагаю, что запускаемый из композера git ставит такие права. Помогите разобраться, как заставить ставить права по максимуму в этом случае. Запуск из под рута проблемы не решает.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решается установкой виртуалки через homestead

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].